# I am getting "Index 6 out of bounds for length 6" while executing my web application

Tags: java, arrays, servlets, web-applications

I am trying to write a servlet that takes in values from the form and stores it in a table called material. The page is as follows : 
[This is my page.The number of entries can be anything between 1 to 6.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TutYW.png)

For my test run, I only had a single entry and on clicking submit I get the error "index 6 out of bounds for length 6". Note: A single entry means I fill details of only one material out of 6.

This is how my servlet code looks like. I have used request.getParameterValues to input the form data in arrays.

```
Class.forName(driver);

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO material" + " (PassNumber, InitiatingOfficer, staff_id, Materials, Quantity, Unit, Date_of_return) VALUES " + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
        for(int i=0; i<Materials.length; i++){
           st.setString(1, PassNumber);
           st.setString(2, InitiatingOfficer);
           st.setInt(3, staff_id);
           st.setString(4, Materials[i]);
           st.setString(5, Quantity[i]);
           st.setString(6, Unit[i]);
           st.setString(7, Date[i]);
           st.addBatch();
        }
        st.executeBatch();
```

This is how I have initialised the arrays:

```
public class raisegatepass extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
    String PassNumber = generatePIN();  //Pass Number
    String InitiatingOfficer = loginBean.getName();  // Name
    int staff_id = loginBean.getstaffid();    // Staff ID
     String[] Materials = request.getParameterValues("materialInfo"); // Array containing Material Name list
     String[] Unit = request.getParameterValues("materialUnit"); // Array containing Unit
     String[] Quantity = request.getParameterValues("materialQuantity");  // Array containing Quantity in string
      String[] Date = request.getParameterValues("materialDate"); // date of return
```

Also, is this the right way to enter data into my table whenever I do not know in advance how many rows the user will fill?

Edit: Here is my complete code for the servlet

public class raisegatepass extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
    String PassNumber = generatePIN();  //Pass Number
    String InitiatingOfficer = loginBean.getName();  // Name
    int staff_id = loginBean.getstaffid();    // Staff ID
     String[] Materials = request.getParameterValues("materialInfo"); // Array containing Material Name list
     String[] Unit = request.getParameterValues("materialUnit"); // Array containing Unit
     String[] Quantity = request.getParameterValues("materialQuantity");  // Array containing Quantity in string
      String[] Date = request.getParameterValues("materialDate"); // date of return

      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String connectionUrl = //Url
      String database = //Database
      String userid = //userid
      String password = //password

      try {
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO material" + " (PassNumber, InitiatingOfficer, staff_id, Materials, Quantity, Unit, Date_of_return) VALUES " + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
        for(int i=0; i<Materials.length; i++){
           st.setString(1, PassNumber);
           st.setString(2, InitiatingOfficer);
           st.setInt(3, staff_id);
           st.setString(4, Materials[i]);
           st.setString(5, Quantity[i]);
           st.setString(6, Unit[i]);
           st.setString(7, Date[i]);
           st.addBatch();
        }
        st.executeBatch();

    } catch(Exception e)
    {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
          RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("gatepass_raise.jsp");
      view.forward(request, response);
    }     

      public String generatePIN() 
{   
   int x = (int)(Math.random() * 6);
   x = x + 1;
   Random r = new Random();
   char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'A');
   String randomPIN = c + (x + "") + ( ((int)(Math.random()*100)) + "" );
  return randomPIN;
}
```

}

Comment: The code where the error happens seems to be omitted here. Somewhere array[6] is called, which is out of bounds (the highest index is array[5]).

Comment: @Serge I have edited my question and have added my whole code for your reference. I initially had thought the problem was arising in the loop that is why uploaded only that part. Anyway, please have a look at my latest edit for the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the length of all arrays is the same, this code should be fine, but my guess is it´s not the same (only guessing, since no exception stack provided). What do you have in the view (jsp)? Materials possibly having more elements than Unit, Quantity, Date?

To check the length, you can add some debug outputs in the servlet, like that:

```
String[] Date = request.getParameterValues("materialDate"); // date of return
...
System.out.println("Materials length: " + Materials.length));
System.out.println("Unit length: " + Unit.length));
System.out.println("Quantity length: " + Quantity.length));
System.out.println("Date length: " + Date.length));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was supposed to be of same length and when I checked my lengths they came out different due to some null values. I removed the null values from the arrays and it works now!